# Swift 2.x cannot set MapView Region

Tags: ios, swift2, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

it's like 5 hours I am stick with this issue. I recently started Swift, cannot say I like it and I get issues after issues. I am trying to do very simple thing. I have class that has date(NSDate), durration(NSTimeInterval), locationName(String) and locationMapView(MKMapView). It doesn't implement any protocol. I want in my initializer to get coordinate and set it to MapView. I found few guides on how to do it but it happens I have problem with basic thing. I cannot even set a region. Here is fragment of init:

```
    self.locationMapView = MKMapView();

    let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.03, longitude: 118.14)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(100, 80)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)
    self.locationMapView!.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    print(String(region))
    print("---")
    print(String(locationMapView!.region))
```

And here what is displayed in console:

```
    MKCoordinateRegion(center: __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.03, longitude: 118.14), span: __C.MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 100.0, longitudeDelta: 80.0))
        ---
    MKCoordinateRegion(center: __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: nan, longitude: nan), span: __C.MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0, longitudeDelta: 0.0))
```

It took me a while to figure it out that values aren't assigned, but I have no idea why. I found this kind of code in many answers and guides. What is wrong with my implementation?

Thank you everyone for help and I am sorry if this is something stupid.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
self.locationMapView = MKMapView();
```

You created a map view but you didn't assign it a frame. Thus it has zero size. Thus it cannot have a region.

Comment: That's basically what I wrote in my self answer (I think). The only mystery is why I cannot create MapView before and later assign it to specific frame? I mean it seams logical to first do all logic in object and then just assign it where I want to use it. Especially if I want to use the same map in 2 different places.

Comment: @Bielik I think your first code would have worked fine if you had created the map view properly. Instead of saying `self.locationMapView = MKMapView()`, you say `self.locationMapView = MKMapView(frame:someRealFrame)`. — Your second point, "I want to use the same map in 2 different place", makes no sense to me; a view cannot appear in two different places at once.

Comment: I am starting to understand something. As I said I just started swift and don't exactly know what is frame in this context. About this 2 places maybe I will explain. As I said this locationMapView is part of simple class (4 variables/properties). I wanted to keep MapView ready to display in same places, more precisely in tableViewCell and it a detailed view after clicking on that cell. That's what I meant by saying I want to display it in 2 different places. So by creating this frame I could do that?

Comment: The frame has nothing to do with that. Your original question was about why the region could not be set; I answered that. — You cannot display _this_ map view in 2 different places. A view cannot be in two places at once! The whole idea makes no sense. It's just like how _you_ cannot be in two places at once. You could display two _different_ map views in 2 different places.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. Just to explain, I was doing mainly c# using WPF for UI and never actually thought of property as something purely visual. I always thought of that as something that is just storing data for the display (like data binding). Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Model - View - Controller. A UIView is _view_: it is something that _actually appears in the interface_. It is what the user sees. It is what the user touches. Store data in model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104745/discussion-between-bielik-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

PARTIAL ANSWER:

I have dig a little deeper and I think I have my answer. It seems you cannot assign anything to MKMapView object if it isn't directly connected to display (via outlet).

What I did was removed everything connected with MapView from my class and moved it to UITableViewCell based class which holds outlet to specific MapView. There I was able to assign coordinates and everything worked as intended.

NOTE: You still cannot operate on additional variable like tempMapView and then assign it to actual MapView. It won't work.

I hope I helped people who stumbled on the same problem as I did. If anyone knows why you cannot work with MapView which isn't directly connected to display or how to work it around please let me know.